# how to solve - oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingTokenError while authenticating GoogleAssistant oauth-tool URL

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, raspberry-pi-zero, google-assistant

When i run the below command in my Raspberrypi for authenticating google assistant api

"google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /home/pi/client_secret_hsjkhdakjs.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless"

im getting the bewlow error.:

few more lines of error traceback....

File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 360, in fetch_token
self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py", line 421, in parse_request_body_response
self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 431, in parse_token_response
validate_token_parameters(params)
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 441, in validate_token_parameters
raise MissingTokenError(description="Missing access token parameter.")
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingTokenError: (missing_token) Missing access token parameter.

Please guide me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this, Its really urgent